# (3/p) as a legendre symbol

Tags: elementary-number-theory

As part of a past exam paper (3/p) equalling 1 is a necessary part of the answer.

The answer page gives this as correct if p is congruent to plus/minus 1 mod 12.

Can anybody explain to me how to actually get to this answer? I know properties of the legendre symbol and how to manipulate it but I don't know how it has got to this answer.

Thanks

Comment: Does your knowledge of manipulating the Legendre symbol include quadratic reciprocity?

Comment: Yes, I tried using it as (p/3) and then actually writing out the congruence and trying different numbers, but It didn't lead anywhere.

Comment: Also as you have to multiply by (-1)^(p-1)/2  How would I know if it is 1 or -1 without knowing what p is?

Answer (score 3):

$$p=1\pmod{12}\implies p=1+12k\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z\implies p=1\pmod 3\,,\,\pmod 4\implies$$

$$\binom3p=\binom13=1$$

$$p=-1\pmod{12}\implies p=-1+12k\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z\implies p=-1\pmod 3\,,\,\pmod 4$$

But then we know that

$$\binom3p=-\binom p3=-\binom 23=1$$

**Added:** Now suppose that

$$1=\binom 3p=\binom p3^{\frac{p-1}2}\iff\begin{cases}p=1\pmod 4\\{}\\p=3\pmod 4\;\;\text{and}\;\;p=-1\pmod 3\end{cases}$$

Now deduce that it must be $\;p=\pm1\pmod{12}\;$ ...!

Comment: I understood this up until the first (mod 4) but I don't think this answer will work as it starts with using 12 which is only given in the answers.

Comment: Then I think you expressed your actual question poorly: should it be "Prove that $\;3\;$  is a quadratic residue modulo $\;p\;$ iff $\;p=\pm1\pmod {12}\;$ " ?